# Infinity recursive simulation on a turing machine?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, infinity

Do you think, that it would be possible to run a infinite and recursive simulation of the universe on an turing machine?

Comment: This is an opinion based question that does not fit with the PSE format.

Comment: This post might help, but it requires some knowledge of computer science: [Falsifiability and Gandy’s variant of the Church-Turing thesis](https://egtheory.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/falsifiability-and-gandys-variant-of-the-church-turing-thesis/).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of the Turing machine is a mathematical concept representing exactly that which can be computed (is 'decidable'). Therefore, the answer to that question depends on your worldview.

In a strict scientific-deterministic worldview, the world could ultimately be modeled in a mathematical model, and iterations of that model would be well-defined. Therefore, by definition, a Turing machine could implement that model.

Other worldviews may not accommodate  for such possibilities. Hume comes to mind, claiming causation cannot be proven to exist.